# Кирпичная верстка как правильно задать padding чтобы все не рухнуло

Tags: css

Есть 3 блока и в каждой по две картинки.

1.В первом блоке `364 x 364` вторая картинка `364 x 590`

2.Во втором сначала `364 x 590` а потом `364 x 364`

3.В третьем тоже самое что и в первом

При ширине меньше *1200 пикселей до 768 пикселей* эти картины прилипают друг к другу и никакой padding и margin не помогает.

> Вопрос: КАК вообще разделить их друг от друга?

```css
.our-works {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.img-holder-our-works {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* box-sizing: border-box !important; */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .our-work-empty-img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container our-works">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <h1 class="our-work">our best work</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="img-holder-our-works">
              <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                  <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x364">
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="img-holder-our-works">
              <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                  <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x590">
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="img-holder-our-works">
              <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                  <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x590">
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="img-holder-our-works">
              <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                  <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x364">
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 d-xs-block d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-block d-xl-block col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="img-holder-our-works">
              <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                  <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x364">
              </a>
          </div> 
          <div class="img-holder-our-works">
              <a href="https://placeholder.com">
                  <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x590">
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если эмитировать внешний отступ добавив `outline` получится как бы то что надо !

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.our-works {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.img-holder-our-works {
  outline: 4px solid #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .our-work-empty-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container our-works" style="background:#fff;">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="our-work">our best work</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="img-holder-our-works">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x364">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="img-holder-our-works">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x590">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="img-holder-our-works">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x590">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="img-holder-our-works">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x364">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 d-xs-block d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-block d-xl-block col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="img-holder-our-works">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x364">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="img-holder-our-works">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/364x590">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо что помогли